# R: Passing Column Names to Function w/ dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to set up a function in R which prepares data in a specific format to be fed into a correlogram. When manipulating datasets I tend to use dplyr due to its clarity and ease of use, but I am running into problems trying to pass a dataset and specified column names into this function while using dplyr.

This is the set up, included here (in slightly abbreviated form) for clarity. I have not encountered any errors with this and before posting this I confirmed corrData is set up properly:

```
library(corrplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

table2a <- table2 %>%
    mutate(example_index = str_c(country,year, sep="."))
```

Here is the actual function:

```
prepCorr <- function(dtable, x2, index2) { 

  practice <- dtable %>%
    select(index2, x2) %>%
    mutate(count=1) %>%
    complete(index2, x2)

  practice$count[is.na(practice$count)] <- 0

  practice <- spread(practice, key = x2, value = count)

  M <- cor(practice)
  return(M)
}

prepCorr(table2a, type, example_index)
```

Whenever I run this function I get:

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'example_index' not found
```

I have also tried to take advantage of quosures to fix this, but recieve a different error when I do so. When I run the following modified code:

```
prepCorr <- function(dtable, x2, index2) { 
  x2 <- enquo(x2)
  index2 <- enquo(index2)

  practice <- dtable %>%
    select(!!index2, !!x2) %>%
    mutate(count=1) %>%
    complete(!!index2, !!x2)

  practice$count[is.na(practice$count)] <- 0

  practice <- spread(practice, key = !!x2, value = count)

  return(cor(practice))
}

prepCorr(table2a, type, example_index)
```

I get:

```
Error in !index2 : invalid argument type
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix this? I believe I am using dplyr 0.7 for clarification.

UPDATE: replaced old example with reproducible example.

Comment: Can you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Would it be alright if I edited the question to use table2 from the tidyverse package rather than the tables shown here? It should work for this purpose nicely.

Comment: Sure, as long as it gives the same error and we can use it to "debug"

Comment: Ok, it should be reproducible now, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Save the RStudio for RStudio-speific problems. (The RStudio interface, or code that works in RGui or on the R command line, but not in RStudio.)

Comment: Your example with quosures works for me (with dplyr 0.7.2 and tidyr 0.7.0).

Comment: Any suggestions as to why this might be encountering issues? It seems like it is processing !!index2 as !(!index2). Can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(df, col1, col2) {
              col1 <- enquo(col1)     # need to quote
              col2 <- enquo(col2)
              df1 <- df %>%
                       select(!!col1, !!col2)   #!! unquotes
              return(df1)
         }

myfun(mtcars, cyl, gear)
```

You can learn more here [link](http://rmhogervorst.nl/cleancode/blog/2016/06/13/NSE_standard_evaluation_dplyr.html) about `NSE` vs `SE`

Comment: When I run that, using say index2 <- enquo(index2) I keep getting: ** "Error in !index2 : invalid argument type'" **

Comment: I am using double exclamation marks, but weirdly the error only returns !index2 rather than !!index2

Comment: Looks like it's failing on `tidyr::complete`. You should ask a separate question to see if NSE evaluations are possible with `tidyr::complete` and `tidyr::spread`

Comment: It fails if I just use tidyr::select, and it fails before tidyr::spread is even processed (or if I comment tidyr::spread out and only test the first block of tidyr code)

Comment: Use `dplyr::select` instead

Comment: It seems like it is processing !!index2 as !(!index2). Can I avoid that?